# Hosting a website but public ip keeps changing

Tags: ip, hosting, public

I am currently hosting the site theviewbeyond.co.uk on a server at home, the issue is my public IP will change every month or so.

I purchased the domain from godaddy, is there anything i can do to make godaddy update my IP automatically or somehow configure DDNS to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service): You need a DNS service, but it has to be dynamic.

[No-ip](http://no-ip.com) (and others) offers free dynamic DNS, but only for subdomains of their domains.

Others offer free DNS hosting, but are not dynamic. [he.net](http://dns.he.net) seems to offer free DNS hosting *and* can be marked as dynamic. At the end of the wikipedia article are some other links to free DNS hosting, but do check if you accept dynamic updates.

Finally, you need install the appropriate tool in your server to detect IP changes, and to send the update to the DNS host.

Comment: Would installing the tool effect it if cloudflare is managing my DNS, the issue is they dont update when my IP changes

Comment: I can't find any reference on cloudflare indicating they have dynamic updating. he.net (link in answer), ClouDNS, FreeDNS, and others do seem to mention this in their webpages.